# Debugging android - how to get bugreport output from a user?

Tags: android, debugging, adb

What is the easiest way for a user to send me the output from 'adb bugreport'?  Asking them to install the sdk and hook up USB debugging is too hard.  Is there an app that will just dump that out and email it, or some other trick?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[aLogCat](http://www.appbrain.com/app/org.jtb.alogcat) can view and email you the LogCat information. there is also [Log Collector](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.xtralogic.android.logcollector) which has intents you can call directly. There is also another one called [Log Collector](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.twofortyfouram.logcollector_paid), but it is not free, and that seems a bit strange to ask a user to buy an app to report bugs... but that is just me I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at

http://acra.ch/

It's open source, highly configurable, yet easy to set up and you can choose the report's destiny. Beside the stack trace, you'll get lot's of context information. You should start here to get an idea what you are about:

https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup